# Blazor .NET 8 [RenderModeInteractiveAuto] getting an error

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

[Screenshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2MuI.png)

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RenderModeInteractiveAutoAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    DemoBlazorCRUDOperationsWithDotNet8.Client  D:\MyLearningSoftwareDevelopment\LearnBlazor\BlazorCrudOperation\DemoBlazorCRUDOperationsWithDotNet8\DemoBlazorCRUDOperationsWithDotNet8\DemoBlazorCRUDOperationsWithDotNet8.Client\Pages\Counter.razor 2   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RenderModeInteractiveAutoAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    DemoBlazorCRUDOperationsWithDotNet8.Client  D:\MyLearningSoftwareDevelopment\LearnBlazor\BlazorCrudOperation\DemoBlazorCRUDOperationsWithDotNet8\DemoBlazorCRUDOperationsWithDotNet8\DemoBlazorCRUDOperationsWithDotNet8.Client\Pages\ManageProduct.razor   3   Active